# How to filter core data based on a store schedule to display only those open?

Tags: ios, if-statement, undeclared-identifier

How should I declare this variable so that I dont get a warning from XCode saying unused variable:

```
// Set it based on TimeComparator
        if ([TimeComparator dealWithTimeStrings2:locationObject.hor_LV]) {
            NSString * estado = @"Open";
        } else {
            NSString * estado = @"Closed";
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the compiler warning and the error because `NSString * estado` is declared locally
in the if-block and locally in the else-block.
(Declaring a variable in a `{ ... }` block restricts the visibility to that block.) What you probably meant is

```
NSString * estado;
if ([TimeComparator dealWithTimeStrings2:locationObject.hor_LV]) {
    estado = @"Open";
} else {
    estado = @"Closed";
}
//... use estado ...
```